# Determinant of adjoint representation

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, root-systems, lie-derivative

Let $G$ be a semisimple Lie group with Iwasawa decomposition $G=KAN$ and consider the determinant of the adjoint representation $\operatorname{Ad}$ of $AN$.

I want to determine what the derived representation looks like on $\mathfrak{a}$ (on $\mathfrak{n}$ it is obviously zero). I suspect that one can calculate this values using the root space decomposition w.r.t the root system $(\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{a})$.

I know that the derivative of the determinant is the trace. Does this help?
Thanks for any hints.

Comment: What is $AN$? A Borel subgroup?  Or a parabolic subgroup?

Comment: Also, are you assuming that $G$ is split?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My question is answered in Knapps book *Lie groups beyond an introduction* on page 472 (Integration, Application to Reductive Lie Groups). The answer is $2\rho\log(a)$, where $\rho$ is the half sum of positive roots (counted with multiplicities).

Comment: It was page 540 in the version of the book I have.