# How is the Zariski topology (?) being used in the proof of the KAN decomposition of a semisimple Lie group?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-groups, zariski-topology, semisimple-lie-algebras

On page 13 of [this PDF](https://www.math.stonybrook.edu/%7Eaknapp/books/green/file4.pdf) the existence of KAN decompositions of semisimple Lie groups is proven. The proof uses the fact that the matrix multiplication map is *regular* to conclude that the image of $(K,A,N)\mapsto KAN$ is an *open* set. I believe that this is using facts about the Zariski topology to conclude Zariski-openness. How does one prove that the image is Zariski-open?

[edit]

I'm guessing that the *dimensionality* is key to showing Zariski-openness. A Zariski closed subset $S$ of a variety $V$ has the same dimensionality as $V$ iff $S$ is... also Zariski open?

[edit]

Actually, no that's wrong. I think maybe the detour to proving Zariski openness is unnecessary and wrong. Actually, the image is Zariski closed, but also has the same dimensionality as the codomain, and therefore by facts about Zariski topology the image is the whole space. Talking about Zariski openness is totally unnecessary here.

Comment: The whole source reads as if $G$ is a real Lie group, and the topology they use is the one coming from the Lie structure, which should be much finer than the Zariski topology. It talks about diffeomorphisms and compact subgroups and simply-connected and all that jazz. I don't think Zariski comes ever into play here. By the way, the lemma 6.44 which is used on the page you quote is absent from the file, not good.

Comment: I mean, yes it mentions regular maps, which would work even for the Zariski topology, but aren't regular maps open even for the manifold topology as long as the dimensions match? That seems to be what they are using there.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Are you aware of a reference to a complete proof of the existence of the KAN decomposition for semisimple Lie groups?

Comment: I would be surprised if the standard sources (https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194419/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/832624/96384, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461029/96384) did *not* contain proofs of what is often called the Iwasawa decomposition. Apparently, Knapp uses it, so might have proven it: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3072648/96384